# Hacer un Deploy Remoto Tomcat con Ecipse/Spring Tool suit

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

¿Cómo hacer un deploy remoto de una Aplicación Spring Boot en un servidor Tomcat?

El archivo a ser deploy debe ser un  `war`.

Ya que de esa forma se haría eficiente ya que en el servidor o computadora de trabajo no sería necesario levantar un tomcat por cada uno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Instalar Maven Integration para Eclipse/STS (m2eclipse)

2.- Crear un proyecto Maven

2.1.- `File->New->Project... .>Maven -> Maven Project` (Si ya se ha creado 
sólo importar el proyecto)

2.2.- Siguiente, dejar todos los campos en por defecto.

2.3.- Seleccionar "maven-archetype-webapp" y siguiente.

2.4.- Ingresar un número arbitrario en "Group Id" y "Artifact" (e.g. "org.myorg" para GroupId y "myapp" para Artifact) y hacer click en "Finish".(Puedes observar en la raíz de proyecto el archivo pom.xml)

3.- Editar el archivo pom.xml que se encuentra en tu proyecto y cambiar el hostname por la IP donde se encuentra instalado el tomcat. (Reemplaza yourhost con tu IP)

```
    ...
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    <path>/path-to-deploy</path>
                    <url>http://yourhost:8080/manager/text</url>

                    <server>tomcat7</server>
                    <username>username</username>
                    <password>userpass</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <finalName>Name of Service</finalName>
    </build>
    ...
```

4.- Agregar al archivo `%USERPROFILE%.m2\settings.xml` la siguiente configuración
`%USERPROFILE%` = Ruta hacia la carpeta del usuario.

En Windows
C:\Users\username.m2\settings.xml

```
<settings ...>
    ...
    <servers>
        <server>
          <id>tomcat7</id>
          <username>test</username>
          <password>test</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    ...
</settings>
```

NOTA: El usuario del tomcat debe tener el role `manager-script`, en este caso el usuario `test` tiene asociado dicho role.

5.- Hacer click derecho sobre el proyecto correr maven build

- Luego en Run Configurations editar la entrada de maven y colocar los siguientes parámetros:

`Goals` = tomcat7:redeploy

`User settings`: C:\Users\username.m2\settings.xml